# How will I now save the counter value or the "Textbox" value,so that after refreshing it'll remain persistent there

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how to save the value of TextBox or counter in localstorage??
Is it possible by localstorage,please do tell

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info disabled"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-lg"></i></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id='AddButton' value="+">Like</button>
</div>
<input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="TextBox" value="1">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#AddButton').click( function() {
            var counter = $('#TextBox').val();
                counter++ ;
                    $('#TextBox').val(counter);
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, there are lots of examples everywhere, including StackOverflow. Please use search.

Answer (score 0):

Use setItem Method in order to save TextBox's value:

```
var text = $('#TextBox').val();
localStorage.setItem("mytext", text);
```

then for getting the text after refresh use getItem method:

```
localStorage.getItem("mytext");
```

Answer (score 0):

To store value in `localStorage`

```
localStorage.setItem("counter", counter);
```

To retrieve value from `localStorage`

```
var = localStorage.getItem("counter");
```